# Deleting Datastore tables from the Dropbox API console

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, datastore

I’m developing an Android app using a Dropbox Datastore. I can view my tables and records from the Dropbox API console webpage. Is there a way to delete a table from this website location? Right now I’m executing a special method from within my app to clear a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the datastore browser is read-only. But, on that page, you could execute JavaScript in your browser's console to do it. E.g.

`datastore_manager.deleteDatastore('default');`

Comment: Yes, thank you. Amazing that they wouldn't include a link/button to do this on the page...